# Set cookies with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cookies, yii2

I know this topic was discussed several times. But I can't really figure out why my example is not working.

I have tested it locally and it works.
[image: localhost-cookie-storing]

As you can see  there are some `received cookies`.
But on the real web site it is not working. The code is exactly the same.
[image]

 As you can see there are **only** `sent cookies`.

JS and PHP sides are very simple. This is for sure not the coding problem.
This is for example server side (Yii2 PHP framework)

      `$cookie = new Cookie();
      $cookie->name = 'agree-terms';
      $cookie->value = '1';
      $cookie->expire = time() + 2592000;
      Yii::$app->getResponse()->getCookies()->add($cookie);
      echo Json::encode(['success' => true]);`

May be something wrong with requests or can be the server configuration. It appears on cargo2share.com website while clicking on close button of cookie agreements block on the bottom of the page.

Any hints are appreciated.

EDIT comparing the response headers:
localhost:
[image]

and live version
[image]

Comment: check out actual http response

Comment: Yes it is okay. In both cases it is a json response {'success' => true}

Comment: http response includes http headers, check them

Comment: @Lashane yes I see nothing strange. Please look at the EDIT. The same problem, that cookies are not set. Any ideas?

Comment: so, on your localhost you set cookie with http only param, but on prod server you're using https, this is why cookie is not sent, grep on all files to find out where httpOnly is set to true

Comment: also, your php settings could do that `session.cookie_httponly`

Comment: I have checked everything. httpOnly was on false while setting the cookie on server side. Also I checked the phpinfo() and session.cookie_httponly was on off. My solution was just to use JS to store the cookie and to use $_COOKIE on server side.